# I have some problems using my app for the second time

Tags: java, android

I have developed an app using Android Studio, which include login and register activities. when I copied my code to my new computer I have launched the app for the first time and it worked just fine. The day after, when I was trying again to launch the app once again. I wasn't able to sign-in to an existing user. I even could not create a new one. Does someone have any idea what caused it' and how could it be fixed?

Comment: add your code also the logcat

Comment: post your code here

Comment: you should debug it to see what is wrong. We can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no details at all..

- Do you store the user credentials on a db?(it could be that you cannot login because you didn't connect correctly to the db) which type of db? is a Web service to an admin panel or some code posted on a hosting/vps?
- Find out which is the error inside the logcat and post ONLY the error, maybe the stacktrace can help you.
- So you can launch the app but the data inside is missing(credentials).. Do you see everything as usual or are there any images/details missing?
- Stupid but easy to forget: do you have an active internet connection on the emulator?
- have you tried to debug the code, have to tried to debug at least the authentication/register process?

Add more details, check your manifest is ok and you have all the permissions(internet, wifi or anything else), post the logcat error(if there is an error) or post the debug error, then someone can answer